# What's Rose putting down her top in New Earth?

Tags: doctor-who

In the first episode of Doctor Who's second season, *New Earth*, there's this scene where Rose (or Cassandra in Rose's body) is suddenly missing the blue jacket she was wearing up until then (what's that about?). She says something along the lines of:

> "Never trust a cat..."

after which a lingering medium close-up shows her hiding something down her top.

Is this the "perfume" she uses to knock the Doctor out later on? She seems to enjoy placing it down there for some reason... I thought the previous scene had established she'd found Rose's mobile phone in her back pocket, so why not just put it there?

Answer (score 2):

The line is

> "Never trust a nun, never trust a nurse [pause] and never trust a cat.

She then turns to her minion and says

> **"Perfume**".

He hands her the bottle of 'perfume' that she later uses to spray the Doctor into unconsciousness.

[image]

Comment: Right, I see. Strange place to put a perfume, no?

Comment: @user96176 - Don't forget that Cassandra is a uptown girl. She's more used to not having pockets in her clothes.

Comment: @Valorum excellent point - my wife and daughter a both thrilled when they find a dress with pockets!